# How can i create a sequence that differs from another one with some probability p?

Tags: matlab, probability, bit

Hello i have a random sequence of 10 bits x=0100100011

I want to create another sequence y but with probability 0.2 is different than x.That actually means that when i have 10 bits i approximately  expect that 2 out 10 bits are different than my initial sequence.
How can implement that on matlab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that

- each bit has the same probability of being flipped, and
- flips are independient for different bit positions,

you can do it as follows:

```
x = [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1];
p = 0.2; % probability of bit flip
y = xor(x, rand(size(x))<p);
```

On average, `x` and `y` will differ in a fraction `p` of the bits.

#### How it works

`rand(size(x))<p` creates a sequence the same size as `x`, where each element 
 contains `1` with probability `p` and `0` otherwise. Each `1` indicates that the corresponding value in `x` should be changed. This is done with `xor(x, ...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much .It worked perfectly . Can you explain why you use xor ?

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΓιαννάκος Glad it worked. I just added an explanation in the answer

Answer (score 1):

While in the question it is expected that *approximately* 2 out of 10 bits to be different than the initial sequence, in the following answer *exactly* 2 out of 10 bits are different than the initial sequence:

```
x = [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1];
n = 10;
p = 2;

pos = randperm(n, p);
x(pos) = ~x(pos);
```